# parsing twitter response in the form of json to mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, json, twitter

I have successfully connected to the twitter api and have pulled some tweets based on search terms. I have managed to send these tweets to a json file. I wish to save these to a mysql database but with only the twitter id, the text and the person who sent the tweet but I am contently getting this error:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxxxxxx on line 18

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxxxxxx on line 19

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxxxxxx on line 20
Array ( [id] => [text] => [name] => )

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

$str = "working";
$con = mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}else{ 
echo $str;
}

$list = file_get_contents('tweets.json');
$json = json_decode($list, true );
 //print_r($json);

$tweets = array(
    'id' =>     $json->id,
    'text' =>   $json->text,    
    'name' =>   $json->name,
);
print_r($tweets);

$db_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tweets(from, tweet, tweetid) VALUES ('name', 'text','id')");




?>
Array
(
[statuses] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [metadata] => Array
                    (
                        [result_type] => recent
                        [iso_language_code] => en
                    )

                [created_at] => Sun Feb 23 21:50:00 +0000 2014
                [id] => 4.3770592875932E+17
                [id_str] => 437705928759320577
                [text] => 2 new iPhone leads have just broken within 5 minutes of each. What are the odds of that?! No phone for a few days then!!!!
                [source] => Twitter for iPad
                [truncated] => 
                [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
                [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
                [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
                [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
                [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 221418717
                        [id_str] => 221418717
                        [name] => Craig Price
                        [screen_name] => CraigPrice1
                        [location] => Glanamman
                        [description] => Beer & Sport!
                        [url] => 
                        [entities] => Array
                            (
                                [description] => Array
                                    (
                                        [urls] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [protected] => 
                        [followers_count] => 269
                        [friends_count] => 765
                        [listed_count] => 1
                        [created_at] => Tue Nov 30 16:28:40 +0000 2010
                        [favourites_count] => 520
                        [utc_offset] => 0
                        [time_zone] => London
                        [geo_enabled] => 1
                        [verified] => 
                        [statuses_count] => 2852
                        [lang] => en
                        [contributors_enabled] => 
                        [is_translator] => 
                        [is_translation_enabled] => 
                        [profile_background_color] => 0F0F0F
                        [profile_background_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme15/bg.png
                        [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme15/bg.png
                        [profile_background_tile] => 1
                        [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/435485486153756672/cSzrw5eX_normal.jpeg
                        [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/435485486153756672/cSzrw5eX_normal.jpeg
                        [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/221418717/1392662771
                        [profile_link_color] => FA0000
                        [profile_sidebar_border_color] => EB0000
                        [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => C0DFEC
                        [profile_text_color] => 333333
                        [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                        [default_profile] => 
                        [default_profile_image] => 
                        [following] => 
                        [follow_request_sent] => 
                        [notifications] => 
                    )

                [geo] => 
                [coordinates] => 
                [place] => 
                [contributors] => 
                [retweet_count] => 0
                [favorite_count] => 0
                [entities] => Array
                    (
                        [hashtags] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [symbols] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [urls] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_mentions] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [favorited] => 
                [retweeted] => 
                [lang] => en
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [metadata] => Array
                    (
                        [result_type] => recent
                        [iso_language_code] => en
                    )

                [created_at] => Sun Feb 23 21:26:01 +0000 2014
                [id] => 4.3769989372629E+17
                [id_str] => 437699893726289920
                [text] => @Mogz1457 how about a broken IPhone 3 eh?
                [source] => Twitter for iPhone
                [truncated] => 
                [in_reply_to_status_id] => 4.3757491419192E+17
                [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 437574914191917056
                [in_reply_to_user_id] => 347149526
                [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 347149526
                [in_reply_to_screen_name] => Mogz1457
                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2353482857
                        [id_str] => 2353482857
                        [name] => Gwilym McCann
                        [screen_name] => theBigg_Mac
                        [location] => Cymru/Wales
                        [description] => The original Big Mac
                        [url] => 
                        [entities] => Array
                            (
                                [description] => Array
                                    (
                                        [urls] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [protected] => 
                        [followers_count] => 5
                        [friends_count] => 6
                        [listed_count] => 0
                        [created_at] => Wed Feb 19 23:31:15 +0000 2014
                        [favourites_count] => 1
                        [utc_offset] => 
                        [time_zone] => 
                        [geo_enabled] => 
                        [verified] => 
                        [statuses_count] => 3
                        [lang] => en
                        [contributors_enabled] => 
                        [is_translator] => 
                        [is_translation_enabled] => 
                        [profile_background_color] => C0DEED
                        [profile_background_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                        [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                        [profile_background_tile] => 
                        [profile_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png
                        [profile_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png
                        [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2353482857/1392853158
                        [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
                        [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED
                        [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
                        [profile_text_color] => 333333
                        [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                        [default_profile] => 1
                        [default_profile_image] => 1
                        [following] => 
                        [follow_request_sent] => 
                        [notifications] => 
                    )

                [geo] => 
                [coordinates] => 
                [place] => 
                [contributors] => 
                [retweet_count] => 0
                [favorite_count] => 0
                [entities] => Array
                    (
                        [hashtags] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [symbols] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [urls] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_mentions] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [screen_name] => Mogz1457
                                        [name] => Morgan Williams
                                        [id] => 347149526
                                        [id_str] => 347149526
                                        [indices] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 0
                                                [1] => 9
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [favorited] => 
                [retweeted] => 
                [lang] => en
            )
```

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `json_decode($list, true)` return result as associative array. So you have to use `$json['id']` notation

Comment: doing this gives out an Undefined index: id error

Comment: Most likely the json has other structure than you expect. Add output of `$list` var

Comment: I have added some of the output. I appreciate all the help you have given me so far

Comment: sorry about that. here it is in a more readable format

Answer (score 1):

Your json has multidimensional structure. So you have to process it in a loop. Somehow like this:

```
$json = json_decode($list, true);
if (is_array($json['statuses']))
foreach ($json['statuses'] as $item) {
    $id = $item['id']; $text = $item['text']; $from = $item['user']['id'];
    $db_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tweets(from, tweet, tweetid) VALUES ('$from', '$text', '$id')");
}
```